# mysql - query to find SUM accrued per hour per day

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query that will accrue the number of employees on shift, the entire 24 hours day. So when a user takes a shift that begin 2013-06-17 10:00:00 AND ends 14:00:00, I'd like the user to "count" in 5 cells

```
2013-06-17 10 : +1 here
2013-06-17 11 : +1 here
2013-06-17 12 : +1 here
2013-06-17 13 : +1 here
2013-06-17 14 : +1 here
```

This should end up providing me with a 24 hour range, showing me how many employees that are on job in the specific hour.

I have 3 tables that I use.

```
teamslots
---------
id
startdate
starttime
endtime

teamslot_schedule
-----------------
id
slotid (joins to is in teamslots)
userid

shifthours
----------
thehour
```

In shifthours I have 24 records - 0 - 23 one for each hour I need.

I then tried to LEFT JOIN on HOUR(teamslots.starttime) AND GROUP BY startdate,thehour but with no real luck.

Here's my query (that currently returns 24 rows of thehour,null,null)

```
SELECT a.thehour,b.startdate,b.taken FROM shifthours a LEFT JOIN (SELECT startdate,starttime,endtime,count(DISTINCT b.id) as taken FROM teamslots a
LEFT JOIN teamslot_schedule b ON a.id=b.slotid) b ON a.thehour=HOUR(b.starttime)
GROUP BY b.startdate,a.thehour;
```

Could anyone please help me out here - point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Please set up your example schema and test data on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) so we can give you answers you can execute without us having to repeat the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brief idea. Come up with a range of hours on the relevant day (assuming the day is a known in advance for the query) and do a JOIN where this is between the start and end time.

Like this:-

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2013/06/17', INTERVAL thehour HOUR), COUNT(teamslot_schedule.id)
FROM shifthours
LEFT OUTER JOIN teamslots
ON DATE_ADD('2013/06/17', INTERVAL thehour HOUR) BETWEEN starttime AND starttime AND endtime
LEFT OUTER JOIN teamslot_schedule
ON teamslots.id = teamslot_schedule.slotid
GROUP BY DATE_ADD('2013/06/17', INTERVAL thehour HOUR)
```

Note that this is not going to work straight out as I am not sure how your starttime / endtime relate to the startdate.

Comment: Almost there - Thanks Kickstart :D
<code>
SELECT a.thehour,b.startdate,COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) FROM shifthours a
LEFT JOIN teamslots b ON a.thehour BETWEEN HOUR(b.starttime) AND HOUR(b.endtime)
LEFT JOIN teamslot_schedule c ON b.id=c.slotid
WHERE YEAR(b.startdate) = YEAR(now())
GROUP BY b.startdate,a.thehour;
</code>
Only I dont get the hours where no employees are at work. Any ideas ?

Comment: You have put a WHERE clause in place to check the column b.startdate, but this means the LEFT OUTER JOIN onto b lands up working as an INNER JOIN (ie, if there is no matching row the year of b.startdate can never be equal to the current year). If you want to check that (and I presume the month, etc) then put the check from the WHERE clause in the ON clause for the join instead. Can you post up some example data and how you want to cope with endtimes that are on a different day to the starttime / startdate (or do you have an enddate field as well on teamslots?).

Answer (score 0):

The following query will include buckets for hours when no one worked:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(d.startdate + INTERVAL s.thehour HOUR, '%Y-%m-%d %H') AS date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ts.userid) AS users
FROM
    shifthours s
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT startdate FROM teamslots) d
LEFT JOIN
    teamslots t ON t.startdate = d.startdate AND
        s.thehour BETWEEN HOUR(t.starttime) AND HOUR(t.endtime)
LEFT JOIN
    teamslot_schedule ts ON ts.slotid = t.id
GROUP BY
    d.startdate,
    s.thehour
ORDER BY
    d.startdate + INTERVAL s.thehour HOUR;
```

For a working example see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a716/13

The following query will only include rows when someone worked:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(t.startdate + INTERVAL s.thehour HOUR, '%Y-%m-%d %H') AS date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ts.userid) AS users
FROM
    shifthours s
INNER JOIN
    teamslots t ON s.thehour BETWEEN HOUR(t.starttime) AND HOUR(t.endtime)
LEFT JOIN
    teamslot_schedule ts ON ts.slotid = t.id
GROUP BY
    t.startdate,
    s.thehour
ORDER BY
    t.startdate + INTERVAL s.thehour HOUR;
```

For a working example see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a716/15

Comment: Thanks for your code and examples. Only when I apply it to my data, I don't get the hours where no employees are at work.
[code]
SELECT a.thehour,b.startdate,COUNT(c.id) as taken FROM shifthours a
LEFT JOIN teamslots b ON a.thehour BETWEEN HOUR(b.starttime) AND HOUR(b.endtime)
LEFT JOIN teamslot_schedule c ON b.id=c.slotid
WHERE b.fid=67 AND YEAR(b.startdate) = YEAR(now())
GROUP BY b.startdate,a.thehour
ORDER BY b.startdate,a.thehour;
[/code]
(really can't figure out the formatting here :( )

Comment: To include hours where no one worked, you need to include the `WHERE` "outside" your initial query. Here's the example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a716/30